# Python - Increment dictionary values

Tags: python, dictionary, increment

I have this nested `dictionary`:

```
 playlist =  {u'user1': {u'Roads': 1.0, u'Pyramid Song': 1.0, u'Go It Alone': 1.0}}
```

and I'm trying to increment its `float` values by `1.0`:

```
user = playlist.keys()[0]
counts = playlist[user].values()
for c in counts:
    c += 1.0
```

I've come this far.

now, how do I `update` the `dictionary` with the `incremented value`?

Comment: Please don't use code markdown for things that aren't code.

Comment: I don't know what you are talking about..

Comment: You can just do like this `playlist['user1']['Roads'] += 1`. But not really sure what you want to do? You want to increment everthing at the same time, or only selected values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To update float values in the nested dictionary with varying levels of nesting, you need to write a recursive function to walk through the data structure, update the values when they are floats or recall the function when you have a dictionary:

```
def update_floats(d, value=0):
    for i in d:
        if isinstance(d[i], dict):
            update_floats(d[i], value)
        elif isinstance(d[i], float):
            d[i] += value

update_floats(playlist, value=1)
print(playlist)
# {'user1': {'Go It Alone': 2.0, 'Pyramid Song': 2.0, 'Roads': 2.0}}
```

Comment: is there a way, within your function, to tweak it so it increments values only for tracks(`dict` `keys`) already present in `d` when if I load a new `playlist dictionary`?

Comment: That is what this currently does, or you want to give more description so I understand you clearly?

Comment: I am generating new playlists here, and the new results always print the same playlist with incremented values. tracks not present before are not added to dictionary as new keys with value = 1.0, I mean

Comment: Oh. But that would require another function

Comment: should I ask another question and tag you?

Comment: Do ask another one but you don't need to tag me :) You're almost sure to find an answer from others in the community or even myself

Answer (score 2):

If the playlist dictionary is only nested one level deep, you can use the following snippet:

```
for user_key in playlist.keys():
    for song_key in playlist[user_key].keys():
        playlist[user_key][song_key] += 1
```