# Python - function to increment dictionary values

Tags: python, dictionary, increment

Starting from two nested `dictionaries`:

```
p1 = {'user1': {u'Codex': 1.0, u'High And Dry': 1.0, u'Hey': 1.0, u'O': 1.0, u'Videotape': 1.0, u'Pyramid Song': 1.0}}
```

and

```
p2 = {'user1': {u'Codex': 1.0, u'High And Dry': 1.0, u'Hey': 1.0, u'O': 1.0, u'Videotape': 1.0, u'Pyramid Song': 1.0, 
u'x': 1.0, u'y': 1.0, u'w': 1.0, u'z': 1.0}}
```

I am fetching both outer `keys`

```
playlist1 = p1['user1'].keys()
playlist2 = p2['user1'].keys()
```

In order to define an incremental `function` whose purpose is to increment counts for repeated songs, and keep all others unaffected, I wrote:

```
def incremented_playlist(playlist1, playlist2):

    playlist3 = {'user1':{}}

    for song in playlist2:
        if song in playlist1:
            playlist3['user1'][song] = 2.0
        else:
            playlist3['user1'][song] = 1.0


    return playlist3
```

this prints the desired `output` for the example:

```
print incremented_playlist(playlist1, playlist2)
```

i.e

```
{'user1': {u'Pyramid Song': 2.0, u'Videotape': 2.0, u'High And Dry': 2.0, u'Hey': 2.0, u'O': 2.0, u'Codex': 2.0, u'w': 1.0, u'y': 1.0, u'x': 1.0, u'z': 1.0}}
```

but how do I build an increment part where now theres only value assignment?

Is there any `built-in` `python` `class` which does `increment` better?

Comment: Do you want to sum values for matching dictionary values?

Comment: *the increment part of the code* - there's no increment part in your code at the moment, only specific assignment. Can you elaborate your question?

Comment: I'd like to add `+1.0` for whatever `values` there were before for matching `keys`

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest well put, I rephrased it.

Comment: Add `1.0` to `p1` or `p2`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python - Increment dictionary values](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40539411/python-increment-dictionary-values)

Comment: the added value on a new `dict`, `playlist3`

Comment: It still doesn't look clear to me, can you show how should look the desired output?

Comment: I wrote the desired output, no? I want that result, but I can't write down the float value for every `dict`, so I just need a generic increment of `+1.0`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work if I understood you correctly. You have 2 playlists and want to make sum of the ratings in the different playlists. So if I have given to some song ratings 1 in both playlists the sum will be 2, if I gave only in one of them the sum will be 1. This solution will work also if there are ratings different than 1.

```
p1 = {'user1': {u'Codex': 1.0, u'High And Dry': 1.0, u'Hey': 1.0, u'O': 1.0, u'Videotape': 1.0, u'Pyramid Song': 1.0}}
p2 = {'user1': {u'Codex': 1.0, u'High And Dry': 1.0, u'Hey': 1.0, u'O': 1.0, u'Videotape': 1.0, u'Pyramid Song': 1.0,
                u'x': 1.0, u'y': 1.0, u'w': 1.0, u'z': 1.0}}

total = dict()
for user, ratings in p1.items():
    this_user_ratings = ratings
    if user in p2:
        ratings2 = p2[user]
        for k, v in ratings2.items():
            this_user_ratings[k] = this_user_ratings.get(k, 0) + v
    total[user] = this_user_ratings
print(total)
```

Or if you need a solution that will work with arbitrary number of dictionaries (playlists) you may want to use something like this:

```
all_playlists = [p1, p2]

total = dict()
for playlist in all_playlists:
    for user, ratings in playlist.items():
        total.setdefault(user, dict())
        for k, v in ratings.items():
            total[user][k] = total[user].get(k, 0) + v
```

Comment: yes, I was going to say `counts` for every song play, but the times a song is played can be thought of as its ranking as well.